# Azure APIM OAuth Integration with Duende Identity Server

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-api-management, duende-identity-server

I have found similar threads but nothing concrete regarding APIM OAuth integration with Duende Identity Server. We want APIM to function similar to Postman, where you set the authorization parameters (access token URL, clientId/clientSecret, scopes) and the user will be able to generate a token.

What we have:

1. Using Postman, we are able to get a token from Duende using a clientId/clientSecret
2. We can use this token in APIM by manually passing it into the Authorization request header with the value "Bearer (tokenString)"
   [image: Screenshot]
3. All APIM operations for this API can be used with this token until expiry

What we are trying to achieve:

1. Using APIM, we want to get a token from Duende using clientId/clientSecret. We have added an OAauth configuration to APIM that mimics that Authorization setup in Postman. ClientId/ClientSecret and scopes are the same for both.

**Postman auth parameters**

- Add auth data to: Request Headers
- Header Prefix: Bearer
- Grant Type: Client Credentials
- Access Token URL: https://contoso.com/connect/token
- Client Authentication: Send as Basic Auth Header

**APIM auth parameters**

- Authorization grant types: Client Credentials
- Authorization Endpoint URL: https://contoso.com/connect/authorize
- Token endpoint URL: https://contoso.com/connect/token
- Client authentication method: Basic
- Access token sending method: Authorization header

2. We have added an inbound *validate-jwt* policy as follows:

```
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <validate-jwt header-name="Authorization" require-scheme="Bearer">
            <issuer-signing-keys>
                <key>/nD6MI5BtZAtfAViOExO3KDwoHKIaeoiuTqysVDECf2QI=</key>
            </issuer-signing-keys>
            <audiences>
                <audience>@(context.Request.OriginalUrl.Host)</audience>
            </audiences>
            <issuers>
                <issuer>https://contoso.com/connect/token</issuer>
            </issuers>
        </validate-jwt>
    </inbound>
```

3. The user should be able to use the API operations by just passing a clientId/clientSecret, but every request using the APIM OAuth config responds with 401 Unauthorized.
4. I believe there is an issue with how the OAuth is setup in APIM. Alternatively, is APIM going to automatically generate new tokens after expiry? When a token expires in Postman, it requires UI interaction to generate a new token. How would this work in APIM Oauth?